# Pandas print column value if conditioned on another column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'food' : ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'pizza'],
                         'price' : [10, 8, 5, 17]
                        })
```

I'd like to be able to print the value of the `food` column, but only if the corresponding value of the `price` is greater than 7.  I tried to use the following (yes, I know for loops are bad!):

```
if df['price'] > 7:
    print(df['food'])
```

But, I get back the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If I had to use a for loop, what would be the way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Would this do the trick? `df[df["price"] > 7]["food"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this ?

```
df.loc[df['price']>7,:]
```

output:

```
    food    price
0   spam    10
1   ham     8
3   pizza   17
```

Update:
If you only want to show the 'food' column, then you just need to replace the `:` in the `loc`statement with the name of the column. (`:` just means all columns of the dataframe)

```
df.loc[df['price']>=7, 'food']
```

Comment: This prints everything, whereas I wanted to print only the `food` column.  I solved it with iteration (though not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
for idx, elem in enumerate(df['price']):
    if elem > 7:
        print(df['food'][idx])
```